# How to prepare a 10% alcoholic KOH solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, solutions, solvents

I am confused actually. A 10% alcoholic KOH solution means that there is 10g of KOH in 100 ml of ethanol, or 10g KOH in 100 g of ethanol or something entirely different?

Also, I understand that the solution is to be clear. I tried the 10g of KOH in 10 ml of ethanol, and somehow it is a turbid solution. Any thoughts on why it is so? And what could be done to make it clear?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Since you've got a solid and a liquid, the 10% must be by weight. So 10 grams of KOH to 90 grams of solvent.

Comment: KOH pellets are ~15% water. Adjust your weights accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no further clarification in the specification of the 10% (like 10vol% or 10mol%), then this should indicate a mass fraction. Thus, 10% of the mass of the solution is supposed to be $\ce{KOH}$, so you would dissolve 10 g in 90 g ethanol to get the desired solution.

I don't know the precise solubility of $\ce{KOH}$ in ethanol but I assume that, if you are following a protocol, the 10% solution should be clear. Obviously, you have tried to get a 50-something% solution, which is not what you actually want. You might want to dilute your solution with whatever amount of ethanol you need to fill 100 g in total.

Comment: $\pu{38.7 g}$ $\ce{KOH}$ per $\pu{100 g}$ ethanol at $\pu{28 °C}$ according to http://chemister.ru/Database/properties-en.php?dbid=1&id=325 itself citing Рабинович В.А., Хавин З.Я. Краткий химический справочник. - Л.: Химия, 1977.